# HTML5 video not playing in Chrome + Fancybox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, fancybox, html5-video, fancybox-2

i set up this jsFiddle (based on fancybox plugin fiddle) to demonstrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/5EV8r/186/

The fancybox/HTML5 video tag combination doesn't work in chrome, the video doesn't seem to load. Interesting: It works when ChromeDevTools are open.

Right now i'm loading the contents from `.videoTag` (which contains the video) into my fancybox and try to load and play it in the `beforeShow` callback. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you may need to add `AddType video/webm .webm` in your `.htaccess` file. If I place the direct URL of your webm video in Chrome http://media.jilion.com/videos/demo/midnight_sun_sv1_720p.webm it doesn't work either so it's not a fancybox issue

Comment: The direct URL works fine for me. Putting `AddType video/webm .webm` in my .htaccess unfortunately didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

.mp4 has many "background" formats (i think it only supports H.264), try other video formats that chrome/firefox support like this: Webm, ogg, ... ;-)

Comment: i included .mp4 and .webm which should cover all browsers.